# custom opengl compressed texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I am developing mobile games on windows. Our image resources are in the PVR-TC 4 format. When we run our game on simulator, images are decoded by CPU which is really slow, as our PC graphic card don't support GPU decode. Is it possible to make PC OpenGL support PVR-TC or ETC hardware decode?

Comment: If you would modify your app to insert a compute shader to convert the textures to a opengl hardware decodable format in gpu you'd better convert have your textures in another format and choose that if you are on simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot force an implementation to implement a particular extension or image format.

Your best bet is to convert the images yourself offline. That is, instead of loading images of a format your hardware can't handle, load images of the format that it can.

After all, it's not like the images are originally in PVRTC format, right? They were originally authored in a regular format like PNG or whatever, then converted to PVRTC. So just add another conversion for S3TC or whatever format desktop hardware actually supports.

Comment: Thanks for your respond.We didn't do that because the original pngs are not retained for some reason.It is left over from history.Export them and ensure correctness will take a lot of work.As pvrtc and etc are loss compression methods.Convert back in batch is not a good way.

Comment: @YafaceX: "*Convert back in batch is not a good way.*" Yes it is. It's the *only* way. Whatever compression artifacts are in the images are *there*; you'll see them no matter how you view them. So the only thing you can control is what format they're in. Obviously you probably don't want to recompress them in another lossy format, but you do want to decompress them.